# Can't scrape three fields from a table with complicated layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script in python together with selenium to parse three fields `franking credit`,`gross divident` and `further information` from a table available in a website. The last two fields are revealed only when the browser is made to click on a ***circular yellow button having plus sign within it***.

However, when the buttons are clicked, they turn into red which indicates that the information got displayed.

> My script can click on all the buttons but it can't scrape the three fields from that table.

I've attached an image to show you how it really looks like.

I know if I send a post http requests with concerning payload to this `https://www.sharedividends.com.au/wp-content/custom/ajaxfile.php?code=MLT`, I can get all the tabular fields in json but that is not how I wanna solve this.

[Website link](https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/)

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#divTable")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",table)

for items in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.sorting_1"):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",items)
    items.click()

for elems in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#divTable tbody tr"):
    franking_credit = elems.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[5].text
    gross_divident = elems.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[6].text
    further_info = elems.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[7].text
    print(franking_credit,gross_divident,further_info)

driver.quit()
```

Whe I run the above script it throws this error `IndexError: list index out of range` pointing at `franking_credit =` this line.

This is how that table looks like. I've marked the three fields in that table within the image below which I'm interested in.

***[Image link](https://filebin.net/x5adwz7y6hfir2sc)***

***How can I parse the three fields from that table?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting following error because when run automation scripts it showing 20 rows with some other attribute instead of 10 rows.Try the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#divTable")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",table)

for items in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.sorting_1"):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",items)
    items.click()

for elems in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#divTable tbody tr[role='row']"):
    franking_credit = elems.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[5].text
    gross_divident = elems.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[6].get_attribute('textContent')
    further_info = elems.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")[7].get_attribute('textContent')
    print(franking_credit, gross_divident,further_info)
```

**Output on console:**

```
$ 0.0446 $ 0.1486 10.4C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

$ 0.0107 $ 0.0357 2.5C FRANKED@30%; SP ECIAL; DRP SUSP

$ 0.0386 $ 0.1286 9C FRANKED @ 30%; DR P NIL DISCOUNT

$ 0.0437 $ 0.1457 10.2C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

$ 0.0377 $ 0.1257 8.8C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

$ 0.0429 $ 0.1429 10C FRANKED @ 30%; D RP NIL DISCOUNT

$ 0.0373 $ 0.1243 8.7C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

$ 0.0424 $ 0.1414 9.9C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

$ 0.0373 $ 0.1243 8.7C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP

$ 0.0441 $ 0.1471 10.3C FR@30%;0.4C SP ECIAL;DRP;NIL DIS
```

Comment: First `for loop` which is supposed to reveal the content is completely redundant as the expected elements are already there.

Comment: @SIM: When you run automation code you must see more redundant rows with some other class name that is why OP facing indexing issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick!

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/")

for button in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sorting_1"):
    button.click()

# Returns first part of the info
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@role='row']/td"):
    print(item.text)

# Returns second part of info
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='dtr-details']/li"):
        print(a.text)
```

Outputs; [this](https://pastebin.com/04Yq4Yde)

Comment: I could not understand what you meant by that. Could you show me a little bit more of that approach?

Comment: Selenium has a `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` method. Use it like this - `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@role='row']/td")`. This will return a list, just search and/or iterate through that list to find the info you need.

Comment: @MITHU I've edited my answer, should help you a lot now

Comment: You found everything accurately but to keep my current implementation intact, I needed `.get_attribute('textContent')` this very command .

Comment: Yeah `get_attribute("textContent")` can replace the `.text`. I just tested it. Hope this is the answer that worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

To extract the data from the three fields *Franking Credit*, *Gross Divident* and *Further Information* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#divTable"))))
  for elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='divTable_info']//tbody//tr/td[@class='sorting_1']"))):
      elem.click()
  all_fc = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='divTable_info']//tbody//tr//td[position()=6]")))]
  all_gd = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='divTable_info']//tbody//tr//td[position()=7]")))]
  all_fi = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='divTable_info']//tbody//tr[@class='child']//li//span[@class='dtr-data']")))]
  for x,y,z in zip(all_fc, all_gd, all_fi):
      print(x,y,z)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  $ 0.0446 $ 0.1486 10.4C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

  $ 0.0107 $ 0.0357 2.5C FRANKED@30%; SP ECIAL; DRP SUSP

  $ 0.0386 $ 0.1286 9C FRANKED @ 30%; DR P NIL DISCOUNT

  $ 0.0437 $ 0.1457 10.2C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

  $ 0.0377 $ 0.1257 8.8C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

  $ 0.0429 $ 0.1429 10C FRANKED @ 30%; D RP NIL DISCOUNT

  $ 0.0373 $ 0.1243 8.7C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

  $ 0.0424 $ 0.1414 9.9C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT

  $ 0.0373 $ 0.1243 8.7C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP

  $ 0.0441 $ 0.1471 10.3C FR@30%;0.4C SP ECIAL;DRP;NIL DIS
  ```