# Can't pull out a specific field available in every row in a table from a webpage

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get a particular field `Further Information` out of a table from a webpage using vba selenium bindings. I got success when I tried with python in combination with selenium using `textContent` instead of `text` as the latter is scraping nothing. However, the problem is I can't make use of this `textContent` within vba selenium. [This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426734/cant-scrape-three-fields-from-a-table-with-complicated-layout) to my earlier post where I've asked this same question tagging different language.

[Website link](https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/)

I've tried with:

```
Sub ScrapeContent()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/"
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, elem As Object, R&

    driver.get URL

    For Each elem In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divTable']//tbody//tr[@role='row']", timeout:=10000)
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = elem.FindElementByXPath("(.//td)[8]").Text
    Next elem
End Sub
```

The field that I'm interested in:

[image]

When I run my above script, It fetches nothing. It doesn't throw any error either. FYI, the xpaths I've defined within the script is accurate.

***How can I get that particular field (available in every row) out of the table from that website?***

Comment: Please don't offer any solution using different `xpaths` or `selectors` as my intention is to know how I can use `textContent` or something similar in future cases.

Comment: I don't see why `.Text` won't work... are you sure that you are giving the page enough time to put the data into the cell after expanding that part of the table?

Comment: Yes, JeffC. I've given enough time to load that content by increasing the timeout here `timeout:=20000`.

Comment: Does that wait for presence or visibility? My guess is that it waits for presence. It also might be that no matter which it waits for it won't be enough because the element might be visible but the text isn't in there yet because it's generated dynamically.

Comment: Have you noticed that if you maximize the page, the entire table is displayed and you don't have to click the expand button? Doing that might solve your problems. FYI... the reason `textContent` works when `.text` doesn't is because Selenium was designed to interact with the page as a user would. The text you are looking for in the table isn't visible... it's in `display:none` tags. `.text` returns visible text (none) where `textContent` is JavaScript which will return text whether it's visible or not.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there isn't any elegant way of using `textContent` in vba selenium bindings. However, you can go with the following approach for now.

```
Sub ScrapeContent()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.sharedividends.com.au/mlt-dividend-history/"
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, elem As Object, oItem As Object, R&

    driver.get URL

    For Each elem In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divTable']//tbody//tr", timeout:=10000)
        Set oItem = elem.FindElementByXPath("(.//td)[8]", Raise:=False)

        If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = driver.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", oItem)
        End If
    Next elem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies didn't see your stipulation (my bad) on `textContent` and `xpath` so here is an alternative for future readers. However, looks like @sim has the covered.

Gather a collection of all elements matched by

```
.sorting_1
```

Loop that collection and click each one.

Then gather all elements matched by

```
[data-dt-column='7'] .dtr-data
```

and extract the `.text` property.

Something like:

```
Dim elem As Object, elems As Object

Set elems = driver.FindElementsByCss(".sorting_1")

For Each elem in elems
    elem.click
Next

Set elems = driver.FindElementsByCss("[data-dt-column='7'] .dtr-data")
For Each elem in elems
    Debug.Print elem.text
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to observe in [this answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426734/cant-scrape-three-fields-from-a-table-with-complicated-layout/57428826#57428826)

Actually, the text `Further Information 10.4C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT` is available is 2 seperate place:

- When the `circular button having plus sign` is green with the attribute `style="display: none;"`:

[image: display_none]

This the place from where your accepted solution reads the text using `get_attribute('textContent')`

---

Of coarse there can be a better approach.

- In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426734/cant-scrape-three-fields-from-a-table-with-complicated-layout/57428826#57428826) you will find the solution clicks on all the `circular buttons having plus sign` is **green** so they turns **red** as follows:

  ```
  for elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='divTable_info']//tbody//tr/td[@class='sorting_1']"))):
      elem.click()
  ```
- Snapshot:

[image: red_button]

- The text `Further Information 10.4C FRANKED @ 30%; DRP NIL DISCOUNT` is read from a `<span>` tag using **`get_attribute("innerHTML")`** as follows:

[image: span]

---

### Conclusion

Using the same logic you can use either `.Text` or `.Attribute("innerHTML")` through [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to cater to your needs.

> You can find a detailed discussion regarding the usage of `.Text` or `.Attribute("innerHTML")` in [Trying with Selenium + Excel VBA to scrape code from a site in Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135802/trying-with-selenium-excel-vba-to-scrape-code-from-a-site-in-chrome-browser/57136922#57136922)

Comment: You've put nothing but python code and screenshots in a question about VBA. Also, if you'd read the other answers before answering (as you are supposed to), you would have seen that OP has already tried the VBA equivalent of `get_attribute()` and it's not implemented in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `.getAttribute` method.

```
elem.FindElementByXPath("(.//td)[8]").getAttribute(...)
```

Comment: Nope, that won't be of any help. I tried with `.getAttribute("textContent")` already.

Comment: Yep I did. The script throws error (object doesn't support this property or method) if I use `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` or `.getAttribute("innerText")`.